# Managers constantly reminding me how to do my job, yet let my coworkers slip..Why?

Tags: work-experience

I work at a grocery store where I bag groceries. After we're done bagging, we offer to carry the groceries out for customers. I always do it the way my managers want, and one manager even said he thinks I do a wonderful job. Once, our district manager took me to the side and said "Wonderful carry-out service. Thank you." In my 6 month review, I was ranked a 8 out of 9 for carry out and was told that they normally don't rank this high.

Yet, everyday they walk by me and say "Remember the 2+2 and don't ask if you can help, ask which way to the car" Yet half my co-workers don't even offer carry-out service at all.

It seems like my managers like me, they're always giving me good reviews. I'm so confused. What does everyone else think?

Edit: That may be. But I don't understand how district wouldn't get mad that they skip the other employees. Of course I just ignore it, I was just curious what everyone's opinions were on the matter. I always listen to my managers, and I try very hard to do best for my store.

Comment: District will have no clue how the managers are managing to such a detailed level. Also, I would assume the managers don't *scream* this 2+2 and where to go stuff out, so how do you know they don't say it to the other  employees?

Answer (score 10):

> Yet, everyday they walk by me and say "Remember the 2+2 and don't ask
>   if you can help, ask which way to the car" Yet half my co-workers
>   don't even offer carry-out service at all.
>
> It seems like my managers like me, they're always giving me good
>   reviews. I'm so confused. What does everyone else think?

I used to work in a grocery store. I did my fair share of bagging groceries.

Managers there needed to find ways to feel "useful". Constantly reminding workers about this sort of thing tends to make them feel good.

Don't worry about it, just nod and say "Yup, thanks."

Answer (score 8):

You take this general admonition way too personally, as targeting you specifically. Your managers including the district manager think highly of you and they have told you so explicitly. Leave it at that. If they had said "Remember the 2+2 rule, except for Springfairy556 who does not need to be reminded", you'd know within minutes what it's like to walk around with a huge target on your back with your pissed off fellow workers taking potshots at you for being an outlier whenever  management is not looking in their direction. Don't tell us you'd be happier this way.

Comment: yes, Vietnhi is right. You don't want the managers playing favourites. For all we know, this is them grooming the OP.

Comment: @Bharal - You are on the same track I am.  This sounds like they're "polishing" the OP for a potential promotion.  Probably trying to see if he can handle a little pressure and keep his composure.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that your management is being beaten upon to repeat this mantra to all employees on a daily basis. The fact that the other employees aren't delivering the service management expects explains why they think the reminder is necessary. The fact that they're reminding you may just be because it's easier than remembering who to pester, or may be a deliberate attempt not to single you out and risk disturbing your relationship with the other register staff.

If you can simply ignore it and continue doing what you're doing, that's probably the best solution.

If it's really driving you crazy, you could try finding a private moment to talk about this with your manager(s), calmly remind them that you're already following these practices, and ask whether there's any way they could quietly skip over you when walking down the line unless there's something that you actually need to correct or something new you need to know. But they're likely to say "sorry, but the district manager will be unhappy with *me* if I skip you", in which case you're back to "ignore it."

(@VietnhiPhuvan insists that I include a warning that trying to discuss this may make you "look like a bit of a prima donna." I disagree, if it's handled properly. If it's expressed, in private, as "I'm sorry, is there something else I should be doing?", it is extremely unlikely to do any harm.)

But the best answer really is to just let it slide. It isn't about you; it's a required ritual. Try not to take it personally.

Comment: -1 - i wouldn't speak to the managers about this. you're right that it is a mantra, or just manager-speak, or just stylistically (the jnr manager sees the senior manager do it, so he/she does it). but bringing it *up* to some manager is just going to make the OP look like a bit of a prima-donna.

Comment: @bharal: I agree that ignoring it is the better answer. If it's _really_ driving the OP crazy, I'm sure management would rather hear "is there any way we can back off on that" than "you're making me feel unappreciated so I quit."

Comment: @keshlam It all depends on how the OP decides how he wants to react. If the OP chooses not make more of it than there is to it, it won't drive him crazy. If the OP chooses to obsess over it, of course, he'll go crazy over it. People don't always get that no reaction of theirs to an event is inevitable - They get to CHOOSE how they want to react to that event.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan: We're "agreeing at the tops of our voices" again... <smile/>

Comment: @keslam Let's wheel and deal - incorporate elements of the comments as you fit in your answer and I'll upvote your answer - you scratch my back and I scratch yours :)

Comment: Shrug. Edited. If it still doesn't satisfy you, I'll have to live with that.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that they are telling everybody the same thing (as other have said) you just aren't noticing when the others are reminded. It could be that others are being told more than once a day.

Have you talked to other co-workers about this? Can you verify they are being talked to as well? Would that make you feel better about the situation?